# Search is looking at the HTML encoded version of a post, rather than what would be rendered

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, html-entities

I just did a [search for `&lt;`](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%26lt%3B&submit=search) just because I was curious. I was expecting to find posts where the user **explicity wrote `&lt;` in the body or title of the post**, which would only actually match the "lt" part, but still.

Instead, I seem to get every post which includes a `<` character as well, because the search apparently looks at the post while it's still HTML encoded. It actually makes the search results look quite confusing. See:

> [image: What I see in search]

This looks... umm... quite odd. My first thought seeing that result is "why on Earth would they escape the leading angle bracket, and not the closing one?" Visiting the actual question, you find out **they didn't**:

> [image: What I should be seeing]

This seems like it could be very misleading for someone who's *actually* searching for a specific HTML entity within the post, as it returns a boatload of false positives that aren't even relevant.

Comment: Lol HTML entity bug is going rampant these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The search page now properly displays these entries.