# How can I search for images I've uploaded in chat?

Tags: support, chat, search, images, chat-search

I'm looking to find an image I posted in [Super User Root Access](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access) a few weeks ago, when I first discovered a [chat-specific easter egg](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/118/root-access).

I've tried [searching the chat transcripts for `imgur.com*`](https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=imgur.com*&user=262881&room=), but it didn't return any results.

**Is there a way to view a list of images that I've uploaded in chat?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### Is there a way to view a list of images that I've uploaded in chat?

I just searched for "img" posted by "Steven Vascellaro" (user 262881) which returned 6 images that you have posted:

https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=img&user=262881&room=118

I don't know if that returns all images that you have posted, but it does return a "clippy" image (clippy is the Root Access easter egg). Is this the image you were looking for?

> [image]

The following search (removing the room id):

https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=img&user=262881

produces more results, but these seem to include 1-boxed posts as well as images. I don't know why "img" matches 1-boxed posts as not all such posts contain the string "img"

Comment: Boxed posts are likely included when searching `img` because of per-site icons. The URL for MSE's icon is `https://meta.stackexchange.com/content/Sites/stackexchangemeta/img/apple-touch-icon.png`

Comment: @StevenVascellaro more than that, I think it find the actual <img> tag being used when image get oneboxed. (e.g. it found [this message](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/721?m=6227654#6227654) where there's no "img" in the image URL at all.)

Answer (score 4):

I suppose that there is no guarantee that this does not change if the implementation of chat changes. But at the moment, it seems that you can find all oneboxed images you posted by searching for `"ob-image"`. Searching for `onebox` should return all [oneboxed](https://meta.stackexchange.com/tags/onebox/info) content. You can try, for example, https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22ob-image%22&user=262881 or https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=onebox&user=262881. Just for the sake of comparison, where is a search using `img` as suggested in the other answer: https://chat.stackexchange.com/search?q=img&user=262881. (It seems that this returns all messages with oneboxed content.)

I assume that this is because the search actually looks into the HTML source of the post. If you check the source, the messages with oneboxed images contain `<div class="onebox ob-image">`.

Something along these lines was also discussed here: [Search is looking at the HTML encoded version of a post, rather than what would be rendered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146213). (And perhaps you can find some other related posts.)