# Search doesn't render some HTML entities

Tags: bug, search, html-entities

I noticed some HTML entities are not being rendered properly in search:

> [image: Consider the following two sentences: [1] The boy is coming. [2] The boy is singing. (at the same time) How can I join the two sentences using a participle? Can I use any … of the sentences below? [3a] The boy comes singing. [3b] The boy is coming while singing. [3c] The boy is singing while coming. [3d] The boy is coming singing. [3e] The boy is coming, singing. …]

This behavior happens with [all searches that return that post](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22the+boy+is+coming+singing%22+is%3Aq).

I have noticed this happens with at least 3 entities, as can be seen in these searches:

- ELU: [&lbrack;](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%26lbrack%3B)
- ELL: [&lbrack;](https://ell.stackexchange.com/search?q=%26lbrack%3B)
- ELU: [&rbrack](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%26rbrack%3B)
- ELU Meta: [&ast;](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/search?q=%26ast%3B)

This behavior does not happen with all HTML entities:

- A similar bug report (specifically about `&lt;`) can be found [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146213/323179), and was marked [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed). And it does seem to be fixed for `&lt;`.
- It does not work with the accented characters (âçöóČ) as seen [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/289001/323179).
- My own testing has found that most entities are properly rendered. in fact, brackets are properly with `&#91;` and `&#93;`, as seen [in this search](https://english.stackexchange.com/search?q=%22After+having+consulted+a+number+of+resources%22)

---

If you know of any other entities that are not being properly rendered, feel free to leave a comment.

This query may help. It finds posts that use HTML entities (replace `&ast;` with the HTML entity you want to find):

```sql
Select top 50 PostId as [Post Link], text from posthistory
where text like '%&ast;%'
```